# Merge Java and DDMS perspectives in eclipse when developing for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

Ok so I am tired of switching between the DDMS and Java perspectives when developing for android.  Is there any way to customise Eclipse to get the LogCat window with the emulator and thread list on the standard Java perspective? ie. On one screen.

The "Debug" perspective is close to what I need but I can't select the emulator

Comment: just create a new perspective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Choose the Perspective that is closest to what you need using `Window->Open Perspective`
2. Add Views using `Window->Show View->Other`
3. Save the Perspective using `Window->Save Perspective As`